# Multiple IPs+domains+SSL certs for one web site

Tags: ssl, nginx

I would like to have two domains, each with their own SSL cert, each SSL cert has its own IP of course, to point to the same web site on one physical server. The server will have to have two IPs too of course. What is this called? How is this done with nginx? OS is Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create two `server` entries with different `listen` and `ssl_certificate(_key)` directives using the different IP addresses but the same `root` where your shared web pages are stored. For example:

```
server {
  listen 1.2.3.4:443;
  server_name first-domain.example;
  root /srv/html/shared_domain_data;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/first_domain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/first_domain_key.pem;
}

server {
  listen 9.8.7.6:443;
  server_name second-domain.example;
  root /srv/html/shared_domain_data;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/second_domain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/second_domain_key.pem;
}
```

It's called nothing special.